# Check if player sneakning - modPE

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check if a player/entity is steaking? I know you can set it (Entity.setSneaking), but im searching for something like Entity.getSneaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Entity.isSneaking(ent);
```

return true if it is sneaking.

u can change ent to `getPlayerEnt();` if u want to check if u r sneaking!

[[EXTRA STUFF]]

```
Entity.setSneaking(ent,boolean);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add onto what has already been said you can combine that with `Player.getEntity()` which returns the players entity py putting it in the ent variable to apply it to the player also you can get a list of all modpe functions if you go into: block launcher; launcher options; nerdy suff; dump modpe script methods, it creates a file called modsript dump.txt that lists all functions and the required variable types and it says what hooks accept prevent default.